# Should ToBase64String() method work with all image types?

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using the conversion method ToBase64String for some time now without any issues until now. I am basically taking an uploaded image, converting it to a byte array and then using the ToBase64String() method combined with the identified content MIME type to assign to an image tag's source on my page. Here is my method:

```
    protected string RenderImage(byte[] image, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (profilePhoto != null)
            {
                byte[] byteArray = image;
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
                string imageSrc = string.Format("data:"+ contentType +";base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                return imageSrc;                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch Exception
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am working in the MVC framework so I am assigning the returned value as the source of my image tag within a successful ajax function call. A snippet of the code:

```
success: function (result) {
     var newImg = document.getElementById("updatedImage");
     newImg.src = result;
}
```

This has been working fine but lately I've noted that image/png and image/x-png MIME types have not been rendering successfully using this method. I've compared the attributes of these images with attributes of those which have no problem and I can't find any significant differences that would explain the problem.

I have also noted that the problem isn't prevalent with JPG files and if I simply assign a direct path to the png file as the source, the file renders appropriately in the image tag.

I seem to have a knack for running into oddities like this but was hoping someone may be able to give some input as to why this may be occurring.

I would think that the image tag should be able to handle any string provided by the Convert.ToBase64String() method as long as the size of the byte array was within a reasonable limit. And these PNG files are relatively small anyway. About 49KB in size with dimensions of 232 x 232.

Comment: How are you getting the image string?   POST, GET?

Comment: This sounds like a GET size limit issue where the server silently truncates the response.

Comment: Hi Kevin. I am using the POST method. My thoughts were initially the same regarding the size limit as I've had that issue before and resized the image in code to alleviate the problem. But as I stated, the file size is very comparable if not the same in some cases to the JPG files which don't have the problem

Comment: Kevin. I just set a few breakpoints in my code and added a line to acquire the length of the string produced by the method and it would appear as though you first guess was correct. Although the various attributes of the file in comparison with working ones were virtually identical, the actual length of the string produced by the method differs dramatically so I am going to approach the problem from this direction. You did not propose your comment as an answer though, if you could do that I will mark it as an answer so you can acquire your points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting the image string?

This sounds like a GET size limit issue where the server silently truncates the response.

To troubleshoot this further... I would look at the base64 string you are getting via ajax and compare that to the actual image toBase64 inside your method.

Comment: In effort of adding a bit more information after Kevin identified the problem. I went back and found that this issue was only evident in IE8 in my case, which was the platform for my Development tests. As pointed out previously, it is in fact a known issue and particularly with IE8. I was using the Data URI Scheme and IE8 only supports Base64 URI images up to 32kb in size. I further researched and found numerous suggestions to resolve the problem but ended up using the Browser object in my controller. If IE8, return the image path else ToBase64String() method. Works great. Thanks Again!

Comment: Wow excellent follow up!  And glad you were able to get it all working.